# How do I put a listView inside a regular Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I want to create an audio app to promote music. I want to have a regular Activity that has a listView and then a container or two to display standard information about the Artist. Music files will be inside the ListVIew with a button to play and stop the selected song. So to sum this up how should go about putting a list with buttons inside an Activity with other container?  Hopefully this makes sense. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really check out [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) great Notepad tutorial. You create a basic Notepad, which uses a listview, and a database. If you just starting out I can tell you from experience, these tutorials are the best way to learn. There are tons of them out there :).

EDIT: While I could just give you the code to do what you want, you would learn nothing in the process :).